# Excel for Mac VBA - Save as HTML adds an unexpected line break in file name

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I've created a small VBA script in Excel for Mac 2011 that saves a copy of the spreadsheet in HTML format automatically (at the same location where the original file is) every time you save the spreadsheet.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim filename As String

    folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    filename = folderPath & Application.PathSeparator & "dashboard.html"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
        Filename:=filename, _
        FileFormat:=xlHtml
End Sub
```

The problem is that the generated file name has a line break at the end, which is really weird. In `terminal`, the file look like this:

```
-rw-r--r--@   1 user  group    29K Feb 21 10:24 dashboard.html?
drwxr-xr-x   12 user  group   408B Feb 21 10:24 dashboard_files
```

It seems like a bug in `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` VBA routine.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot test this but I was wondering if the same rogue behavior occurs when you drop the *.html* off the *filename* string concatenation and allow the `, FileFormat:=xlHtml` to assign the file extension.

Comment: Just tested it and two things happened: 1) extension `html` was not added automatically, 2) line break problem still occurs. Worth the try, thanks @Jeeped

Comment: Uh, funny thing (well, not really funny), if I use a string `Filename:="Macintosh HD:Users:user:Desktop:dashboard.html",` instead of the variable `filename`, the problem is gone, although, does not satisfy my need.

Comment: This might sound odd, but could you try completely deleting `"dashboard.html"` and recreate it, by hand (don't copy/paste anything).

Comment: And if you put a breakpoint at `filename` and look at the Locals window, does it show the newline character there?

Comment: Indeed, that fixed the problem @joseph4tw, many thanks, I was hitting my head against the wall. If you answer the question I will accept it!

Comment: Thanks yorch! I can't believe my hunch was right! :) lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After confirming in the comments, sometimes there's something funky that goes on when copy/paste'ing strings into the VB Editor. I had a feeling that you may have inadvertently copy and pasted `dashboard.html` but somehow also copied a newline character that came along for the ride, causing you odd issues when saving.

I don't know how I can prove it, but that newline character can get buried in the string and you can't tell it's even there. I've seen it only once before so that's why I asked if you could delete it and re-create it by hand.

I wish I could explain it, and would love to hear someone's feedback on this if they know what's going on.

Comment: I have seen this rogue linefeed character follow a cell's contents when the cell is copied and pasted to another application. Pasting a single cell to Notepad++ comes to mind immediately. Pasting more than a single cell delimits by the tab character (0×09) but still throws either a LF or CRLF at the end. Seems to be some programmer's 'best guess' as to how to adapt copying one or more cells to the clipboard.